# The page.php not show and it's showing index.php in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So, I've a trouble ..

First, I learn to make the wordpress theme. I want to add post type for spesific post and the new taxonomy. So I add 3 new costum posts (practice, music & video) & 3 new taxonomies (type, feature, source). I've make new single file according to the costum posts that are single-practice.php , single-music.php & single-video.php

When I use the costum post, the post is not found 404 as well as the new taxonomy. I try to change the permalinks to plain, and now it's work .. the post showing file single-practice, single-video and single-video as well as the taxonomy, it's showing in the archive file.

Feel good, I change again the permalinks to post name. Sure no problem so far, but .. when I make the about us page and to preview this, the page.php not show and it's showing index.php same with homepage layout. Why? Is there any less code?

Sorry dor my bad english ..